# print.__doc__ vs getattr(__builtin__,"print").__doc__

Tags: python, python-2.x

`print.__doc__` outputs:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

where as

```
>>> getattr(__builtin__,"print").__doc__
```

Outputs:

> ```
> print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
> ```
>
> Prints the values to a stream, or to `sys.stdout` by default. Optional keyword arguments:
>
> file : a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current `sys.stdout`.
>   sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
>   end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.

Can anyone help me understand why `print.__doc__` is giving a syntax error instead of printing the doc string

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Python 2 (or Python < 2.6 to be very exact) `print` is absolutely nothing like a function, and thus does not have docstring. It doesn't even evaluate all of its arguments before it starts printing:

```
>>> print 42, a
42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

`42` was printed before the `a` was evaluated. `print` is a statement that expects 0 to N comma separated expression following it, optionally preceded by the construct `>> file`, the construct `print.__doc__` is illegal. It makes as little sense as `if.__doc__`, or `return.__doc__`.

However starting with Python 2.6, the `print` *function* is available in the `__builtin__` module, but is not used by default as the `print` *statement* collides with it, unless the parsing for `print` the statement is disabled by `from __future__ import print_function`.

Answer (score 9):

Print isn't globally available as a function in Python 2, so you can't treat it as an object. It's a statement.

In Python 3, or Python 2 with `from __future__ import print_function`, however, `print` is a normal function and you can read the `__doc__` attribute.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

> Note: This function is not normally available as a built-in since the name print is recognized as the print statement. To disable the statement and use the print() function, use this future statement at the top of your module:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import print_function
> ```

Comment: +1 It never occurred to me that the `print` function was always available, and that the future import simply disabled the `print` statement, rather than making the `print` function available.